# action mailer error to deliver email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I am trying implementing send mail through action mailer in rails related code are..

my mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
          class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default :from => "debasish@thejaingroup.com"
     def registration_confirmation(user)
        mail(:to=>user.email, :subject =>"Registered")
        end
        end
```

users.controller is

```
  def create
     @user = User.new(user_params)
        respond_to do |format| 
    if @user.save
    UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully   created.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
     format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
   end
  end
```

Here, Your initializer\setup_mail.rb setting will go to the development.rb

```
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 9292 }

    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
      config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        :address     =>"smtp.thejaingroup.com",
         :domain      =>"thejaingroup.com",
         :port        => 587,
       :user_name   =>"debasish@thejaingroup.com",
        :password    =>"************"
        :authentication =>"plain"
       }
```

and my view is  .. user_registration.text.erb ---is

```
            Hi sir you successfully Completed signed..........!
```

my have a error msg after running this apps..
SocketError in UsersController#create
getaddrinfo: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.

Comment: The problem is connecting the smtp server. application unable to connect the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the address you've used here 'smtp.thejaingroup.com' is the address of the valid email service provider. If you are trying to use your gmail, then it should be 'smtp.gmail.com'.

This is the normal gmail configuration.

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :user_name            => ENV['gmail_username'],
  :password             => ENV['gmail_password'],
  :authentication       => "plain",
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

In this case, all the mails would be delivered to your gmail. . If you don't want this to happen, you can try the gem [letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) for development environment. For production env, you may have to use email provider such as mandrill or sendgrid.